# How to search words/strings using TextBox, ListBox, and Button in Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

**Hello Programmer, Gurus, Geeks,**

Please help me with my program. My program is in Visual Basic 2010 pro, I need to know how to search a words or strings in TextBox and ListBox, for detailed explanation about my problem I provide image below:

[image]

As you can see there's a TextBox(Searh Here), Buttons(Search & Clear) and ListBox(w/ a words of Computer, Programmer, Program, Programming).

All I need to know is how can I search a word, for example I type a word "Program" in the TextBox(Search Here), When I click the Button(Search) The word "Program" must be in top of the ListBox instead of the word "Computer" and "Programmer". That's all I want to know, Please help me with this problem, The reason why I have asked this is because we have a final project in Visual Basic 2010, I choose to create a simple dictionary of programming as my project.

**Thank you in advance,**

Marvin/Haqua

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: You don't expect anyone to do your work do you?  Post what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you the solution in C#, so if you're a VB developer you'll have to read-through and understand what I wrote ;) I've also included a number of ommissions so it won't compile. Muwhaha.

```
 public class FooForm : Form {
     private Button _searchButton;
     private TextBox _searchFor;
     private ListBox _list;
     private void SearchButton_Click() {
         String searchFor = _searchFor.Text;
         foreach(Object item in _list.Items) {
             if( String.Equals( item.ToString(), searchFor, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) {
                 _list.SelectedItem = item;
                 break;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I try this, Sorry to say, I'm not a VB Developer, I'm no good in programming but I always try and try to be a good programmer. I hope more answers to come :D